How to detect a template function should impose a more strict concept
I have some code that looks like this:
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>


template<std::forward_iterator Iter>
auto less(Iter i1, Iter i2)
{
    return i1 < i2;
}

int main()
{
    auto vec = std::vector<int>();
    auto list = std::list<int>();

    (void) less(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    //(void) less(list.begin(), list.end());  // error: no match for 'operator<'
}

Basically, the less template function states Iter template parameter has to meet requirements of forward iterator, while the implementation uses operator<, which is provided by random access iterator.
The code works by accident, because it only uses vectors. Is there a compiler warning, static analysis tool, or anything else that could help detect function that requires a more strict concept than it states?
I realise this could be detected with a unit test, but it would be nice to have a tool to guide the testing/fixing effort in a large code base.

Asking for tools is off-topic.

Are you comparing iterators, or the values they point to?.

Iterators. If I was comparing pointed values, the type of the iterator would be irrelevant, wouldn't it?

You could use random_access_iterator instead of forward_iterator - or use std::less.

I think they realise that, and want some warning that the concept chosen doesn't guarantee support for everything used in the function body. I don't know if any tool that does this, but it certainly feels like a static analysis problem.

@TedLyngmo that's the point. OP wants to detect that less has the wrong constraint.

if you had something along the line of a  std::forward_iterator_sekleton that implements the minimum required to satisfy the concept you could write a unit test. Afaik nothing like that exists

I think it'll be hard for a static analysis tool to figure this out without a usage of the "wrong" iterator type. One could add a static_assert where an iterator of the type the concept is checking is used. Example

@TedLyngmo you dont need a "wrong" iterator type. You only need the right forward_iterator type, that has nothing extra, but only what makes it a foward_iterator

@463035818_is_not_an_ai With "wrong" I meant an iterator of the type the concept is checking for, like I showed in the example. Except I used a bidirectional iterator by mistake :-)

One can imagine a static analysis tool that, given less here, looks at the definition of std::forward_iterator, makes a skeleton type that conforms to it, and tries to instantiate that. AFAIK no such tool yet exists

fwiw, on/offtopic is often just a matter of phrasing the question. Don't ask for a tool, because thats offtopic, but ask whether it is possible to generate a skeleton type given some concept (because thats an interesting question ;)

What you are asking for are "C++0x" concepts - they were designed to check for all concept requirements when parsing a template. The concepts were prepared for C++11 but rejected at the last moment. Years later, they developed "one-sided" Concepts-Lite that became C++20 concepts. "One-sided" in the sense they help consumers of templates but not their authors.

It's a little ironic that mypy can correctly do this for type-annotated Python, but there's no obvious way to accomplish it for C++

I think the best thing to do here is a style change to requires statements for everything that is required of the type instead of assuming there is always going to be an std concept that matches.  That way you can look at the code and know it will work.
So your code would be
template<typename Iter> 
requires(
    requires(Iter a, Iter b){a < b;}
)
auto less(Iter i1, Iter i2)
{
    return i1 < i2;
}

It is a little more verbose but it makes it very clear what you want to do here and there is no room for things to "work by accident".

Although I don't think I will go with this approach, the answer makes sense. Thank you.
